# Why is it valid to pass static types in and out of interface methods in C#?

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, .net-core-3.1, c#-8.0, c#-10.0

I noticed that the following code seems to compile just fine, when I would've expected multiple errors:

```
public interface ITest
{
    Math Foo(MathF x, ref Console y);
}
```

Math, MathF, and Console are all static classes - is there any reason why this is valid, or is it just an oddity of the specification/compiler? When attempting to implement the interface, you then receive an error (I guess that means you can make an interface that's impossible to implement, which is kinda cool)

What's more, I can go one worse:

```
using System;

namespace StaticParams
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ITest.Bar(null);
        }

        public interface ITest
        {
            Math Foo(MathF x, ref Console y);

            static void Bar(Math x)
            {
                Baz(x);
            }

            static void Baz(Math x)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Hello World" + x + "!"); // x is null so we can't do much with it
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Hello World!
```

Tested in VS 2022, using both C# 8.0 + .NET Core 3.1, and C# 10.0 + .NET 6.0.4.

Comment: The first interface example also compiles for `.NET 4.8` if you change the `MathF` to `Math`, only with no warnings whatsoever.

Comment: Just like you can write `if(true == true)` in your project. Although it doesn't make sense, it may confuse later maintainer for a whole week.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there any reason why this is valid, or is it just an oddity of the specification/compiler?

Questions like this can be difficult to answer. The strict literal answer is because that's how C#'s grammar is defined.

Quoting from
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/interfaces :

```
interface_declaration
    : attributes? interface_modifier* 'partial'? 'interface'
      identifier variant_type_parameter_list? interface_base?
      type_parameter_constraints_clause* interface_body ';'?
    ;
```

```
interface_body
    : '{' interface_member_declaration* '}'
    ;
```

```
interface_member_declaration
    : interface_method_declaration
    | interface_property_declaration
    | interface_event_declaration
    | interface_indexer_declaration
    ;
```

```
interface_method_declaration
    : attributes? 'new'? return_type identifier type_parameter_list?
      '(' formal_parameter_list? ')' type_parameter_constraints_clause* ';'
    ;
```

> The attributes, return_type, identifier, and formal_parameter_list of an interface method declaration have the same meaning as those of a method declaration in a class ([§14.6](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes#146-methods)).

From there you'll have to knock yourself out with this:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/classes#146-methods

---

But of course that's not really an enlightening answer. I think what you really want to know is "what is the wisdom in allowing insanity like this?". Which of course is an opinion-based question. So I'll answer that with these opinions of mine:

- It would probably just make the language or its implementation more complex to prevent it at this level
- It's already prevented at another level—it's impossible to implement that interface as you pointed out, so already nobody is able to write useful code like that
- Why not allow it when there's already so much other insanity out there?